# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str in password generator

Tags: python-3.x

I try to make a password generator in python with this

```
import random
upper = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"
lower = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
number = "0123456789"
symbol = "!@#$%^&*"
all = number + lower + upper + symbol
leght = 9
password = "".join(random.sample(all, leght))
temp = "pass_temp" + random.randint(0, 9999999)
pas = open(temp.txt, "w")
pas.write(password)
```

and when I run the code, the output says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\vpg\main.py", line 9, in <module>
temp = "pass_temp" + random.randint(0, 9999999)   
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: As the message says, you can't concatenate a string and an integer by just using the `+` operator. Converting the integer to another string will allow it to concatenate two strings which works; `temp = "pass_temp" + str(random.randint(0, 9999999))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Python does not have feature of type coercion. So you cannot use `+` operator between different types.

In your code

```
temp = "pass_temp" + random.randint(0, 9999999)
```

You are adding an integer to a string, which is not possible in python. You can use a string formatter to do this instead

```
temp = f"pass_temp{random.randint(0, 9999999)}"
```

or

```
temp = "pass_temp" + str(random.randint(0, 9999999))
```